# How to update rvm behind a proxy server?

Tags: ruby, git, proxy, rvm

I am behind a proxy server and thus I cannot update rvm with `rvm update`.

I have a CNTLM proxy locally running and all my http connections go succesfully through it.

Though, `rvm update` doesn't work, probably because it is using the git protocol.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem without having to reinstall rvm?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with rvm or what os you are using, but in order for git to use a proxy w/ msysgit I needed to set the http.proxy global config val w/ `git config --global http.proxy <proxy>`

Comment: i am using a ntlmv2-authenticated proxy, and for that I am running a local cntlm proxy that takes care of the http connections. i believe that git doesn't cope with ntlm-v2 authenticated proxies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question applied to some quite old version of rvm. I had to remove rvm:

```
rvm implode
```

and then I reinstalled it and it worked fine.

Comment: what version of RVM were you using?